# SVProgressHud disappear after few seconds

Tags: iphone, ios, svprogresshud

I have added SVProgressHud in my app and work really greats in most of all viewController. But its behave strangely in first child of navigation controller when i present the SVProgressHud it will displayed but after few seconds it will disappear and just activity indicator only displayed.
See this images, Displayed when i show the progressHud

[image]

This will displayed after few seconds

[image]

I am presenting this progress hud in viewDidLoad method here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [SVProgressHUD show];
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:nil maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
    [self performSelector:@selector(CallLanSelectDataWS) withObject:@"" afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

and dismissing the SVProgressHud after process completed.

Comment: Do you need both `show` and `showWithStatus`?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos No just added it. But it does not make any difference if i remove it.

Comment: Are you developing for iOS7? Don't know if SVProgressHUD is already compatible

Comment: @Dilip can you provide the code for `CallLanSelectDataWS`

Comment: @MarcMosby not developing for ios 7 , and tacos its just web service call and at the end i am dismissing the progressHud.

Answer (score 2):

Perform the task in a background thread?

```
[SVProgressHUD show];

//Execute your task in differentthread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [self callLanSelectDataWS];

    // After this task is done switch back to main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"YEAH!"];
    });
});
```

Comment: This will display success HUD But i want to display that activity indicator

Comment: This will display the activity indicator and after your webservice is finished it will display a success HUD (for about a second). Of course you can replace that line with `[SVProgressHUD dismiss]`

Comment: No not working that way. it will remove HUD before service give back response.

Comment: Then place the '[SVProgressHUD dismiss]` wherever your services returns the response. But make sure to switch to main thread.

Comment: Nop same thing, right image also display like the second image in my question.

Answer (score 1):

currently looking for the answer with the same case.

By default SVProgress will dismiss automatically after 5.0s, 
In my case, I'm using hack to disable dismiss

in Swift:

```
SVProgressHUD.setMinimumDismissTimeInterval(.infinity * 5.0)
```

*Maybe set the specified minimum / maximum time interval as your necessary, and force dismiss may help*

Answer (score 0):

You can use ProgressHUD Library, not SVPRogressHUD:

```
    ProgressHUD.show("put here text you want to be below activity indicator", interaction: true)
```

or

```
    ProgressHUD.show("", interaction: true)
```

put empty if you don't want any text below.

And when you want to dismiss it just type in:

```
    ProgressHUD.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 0):

By default duration is 5 seconds. You can set/change duration for SVProgressHUD like below:

```
SVProgressHUD.setMinimumDismissTimeInterval(20.0) // 20 seconds
```